# How to send subscriber the same email more than once with Mailchimp API 3.0

Tags: email, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using the Mailchimp API to send people who purchase from my website an order confirmation email. Unfortunately, if they order from me a second time, I am prevented from re-sending them the same email. I get this error from my POST request:

```
{ 
 type: 'http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-
 glossary/',
 title: 'Bad Request',
 status: 400,
 detail: 'You’ve already sent this email to the subscriber.'
}
```

Is there anyway to get around this, or will I have to look for a new email software?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this - Mailchimp sets these limits. I would recommend using a transaction based email service instead of Mailchimp to achieve this.